# Perl Regular Expression Question

Tags: regex, perl

I wrote a Perl program which reads text from text file and prints it out.

I want to print out a line which has specific format.

For example, there are some lines like this:

```
information:
Ahmad.prn:592118:2001:7:5:/Essay
Ashford.rtf:903615:2001:6:28:/usr/Essay
Barger.doc:243200:2001:7:4:/home/dir
end of Information.
```

I want to read only these three lines:

```
Ahmad.prn:592118:2001:7:5:/Essay
Ashford.rtf:903615:2001:6:28:/usr/Essay
Barger.doc:243200:2001:7:4:/home/dir
```

I think that the meaning of the fields is:

```
Ahmad.prn <- file name
592118 <- size of file
2001:7:5 <- created date
/Essay <- path of file
```

My code is this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

open (my $infh, "<", $file)||die "cant open";

while(my $line = <$infh>) {
    chomp ($line);
    if ($line =~ /(what regular expression do I have to put in here?)/) {
        print "$line";
    }
}

close ($infh);
```

Comment: You really need to put more information around what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Please state clearly what the line format is. It's not clear whether you just want to strip the first & last lines, match only lines ending with /Essay, match lines matching a:b:c:d:e:f ....

Answer (score 3):

If lines you need always ends with /Essay, you may use following regex

```
/:\/Essay$/
```

**Edit 1**: looks there is middle parts are only numbers, you may match this way.

```
/:\d+:\d+:\d+:\d+:/
```

Comment: i think notation is 'filename:filesize:date:path' em.. '~'

Comment: @misaka, so, middle parts only numbers? added another regex

Comment: @misaka, do you mean split? `split(/:/, $line);` would return 6 items array

Comment: Ahmad.prn:592118:2001:7:5:/Essay    i want to bind 2001:7:5 as one value... but if i use above split code i think i cannot..

Comment: @misaka, for that case, you could split like this, `/([^:]+):(\d+):(\d+:\d+:\d+):(.+)/`, or may be better use match method, `m//` instead of split //.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have this format for Ahmad.prn:592118:2001:7:5:/Essay

```
Ahmad.prn <- file name
592118 <- size of file
2001:7:5 <- created date
/Essay <- path of file
```

you can use this regular expression

```
/^\s*(\S+):(\d+):(\d+:\d+:\d+):(\S+)\s*$/
```

With this you will have file name in $1, Size of the file in $2, Date of creation in $3, Path to the file in $4

I added optional spaces in the start and end of the line, if you want to allow optional spaces after or before : you can add \s*

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;

my $inputText = qq{
Ahmad.prn:592118:2001:7:5:/Essay
Ashford.rtf:903615:2001:6:28:/usr/Essay
Barger.doc:243200:2001:7:4:/home/dir
end of Information.
};

my @input = split /\n/, $inputText;
my $i = 0;
while ($input[$i] !~ /^end of Information.$/) {
    if ($input[$i] !~ /:/) {
        $i++;
        next;
    }
    my ($fileName, $fileSize, $year, $month, $day, $filePath) = split /:/, $input[$i];
    print "$fileName\t $fileSize\t $month/$day/$year\t $filePath\n";
    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$line =~ ([a-zA-Z.]+):(\d+):(\d+):(\d+):(\d+):([\/A-Za-z]+)

$name = $1; #Ahmad.prn
$id = $2; #592118
$year = $3; #2001
$dir = $6; #/Essay
```

Note: loop through it for multiple names